# Ruby on Rails track location in background

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

I started working with Ruby on Rails 3 weeks ago, loving it so far but I need some help.

I'm working on an web app that, among others, tracks the location of a user and stores it periodically in the db.
The javascript for getting the location every minute is working but I don't know how to store this location in the db. 
The script is defined in the application view. I managed to call an update_location action defined in the UsersController using ajax with POST. The lat long columns are updated corectly but a page redirect occurs. I want the update process to be async and hidden from the user.

When I tried using a PUT ajax request (POST with _method=PUT) i get a URL not found for user/:id/location_update.

I am a complete beginner i RoR and even in Web Dev.
P.S. I am using Rails 4.

Edit: Using $.ajax or $.post with _method : "PUT" and URL /update_location triggers the following 500 error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/update_location, application/update_location with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[...]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/.../app/views"
):
```

My update_location action looks like this

```
  def update_location
    @car = Car.find(3)
      if @car.update_attributes(location_params)
      end
  end
```

The db is getting updated but I still get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Rails to just return to jQuery that everything went well.. But by default it's trying to render some HTML to jQuery.

```
  def update_location
    @car = Car.find(3)
    @car.update_attributes(location_params)
    head :ok
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be scoping by this by user id; just use the currently logged in user and post to "/current_location" or something similar. And to accomplish what you're attempting, you should be using jQuery's `post` method to perform an AJAX submission to the server in JavaScript:

```
$.post("/my_location", { "_method": "put", lat: xxx, long: yyy }, function () {
  // done!
}, "JSON");
```

Comment: tried this and It's working like $.ajax, I'm getting the 500 error described in the Question (I just edited the question)